# Find duplicate records in file

Tags: sed, awk, find

I have a text file with lines like below:

```
name1@domainx.com, name1
info@domainy.de, somename
name2@domainz.com, othername
name3@domainx.com, name3
```

How can I find duplicate domains like `domainx.com` with `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: this is typical job for grep, unless you say that the 2nd field could have that pattern (domainx.com) too, and  you just check the first field.

Comment: What are you really after? A list of the domain names where there is more than one entry for the domain name? The actual entries for each domain name where there is more than one entry for the domain name? A list of the domain names and a count of the number of entries, showing only those with more than one entry? All those could have their uses — but they're all different. None of those attribute specific significance to `domainx.com` except as a representative of the class of domain names with more than one entry in the list; if it is of specific interest, the answers are different again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `GNU awk` you can do:

```
$ awk -F'[@,]' '{a[$2]++}END{for(k in a) print a[k],k}' file
1 domainz.com
2 domainx.com
1 domainy.de
```

You can use `sort` to order the output *i.e.* ascending numerical with `-n`:

```
$ awk -F'[@,]' '{a[$2]++}END{for(k in a) print a[k],k}' file | sort -n 
1 domainy.de
1 domainz.com
2 domainx.com
```

Or just to print duplicate domains:

```
$ awk -F'[@,]' '{a[$2]++}END{for(k in a)if (a[k]>1) print k}' file
domainx.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
sed -n '/@domainx.com/ p' yourfile.txt
```

(Actually is `grep` what you should use for that)

Would you like to count them? add an `|nl` to the end.

Using that minilist you gave, using the sed line with `|nl`, outputs this:

```
 1  name1@domainx.com, name1
 2  name3@domainx.com, name3
```

---

What if you need to count how many repetitions have each domain? For that try this:

```
for line in `sed -n 's/.*@\([^,]*\).*/\1/p' yourfile.txt|sort|uniq` ; do 
    echo "$line `grep -c $line yourfile.txt`"
done
```

The output of that is:

```
domainx.com 2
domainy.de 1
domainz.com 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Print only duplicate domains

```
awk -F"[@,]" 'a[$2]++==1 {print $2}'
domainx.com
```

Print a "*" in front of line that are listed duplicated.

```
awk -F"[@,]" '{a[$2]++;if (a[$2]>1) f="* ";print f$0;f=x}'
name1@domainx.com, name1
info@domainy.de, somename
name2@domainz.com, othername
* name3@domainx.com, name3
```

This version paints all line with duplicate domain in color red

```
awk -F"[@,]" '{a[$2]++;b[NR]=$0;c[NR]=$2} END {for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) print ((a[c[i]]>1)?"\033[1;31m":"\033[0m") b[i] "\033[0m"}' file
name1@domainx.com, name1 <-- This line is red
info@domainy.de, somename
name2@domainz.com, othername
name3@domainx.com, name3 <-- This line is red
```

Improved version (reading the file twice):

```
awk -F"[@,]" 'NR==FNR{a[$2]++;next} a[$2]>1 {$0="\033[1;31m" $0 "\033[0m"}1' file file
name1@domainx.com, name1 <-- This line is red
info@domainy.de, somename
name2@domainz.com, othername
name3@domainx.com, name3 <-- This line is red
```

Comment: I like the solution with the red line! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU grep available, you can use the PCRE matcher to do a positive look-behind to extract the domain name. After that `sort` and `uniq` can find duplicate instances:

```
<infile grep -oP '(?<=@)[^,]*' | sort | uniq -d
```

Output:

```
 domainx.com
```